# How can I cancel an NSTimer while it is running? (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have a very simple timer app with an NSTimer. I have a cancel button set up but I'm not sure how to get it working.

Here is my code for the timer. It is triggered when the user presses a start button(not shown).

```
    -(void) timerFunction{
    NSString *timerSeconds = _timerSecondsField.text;
    NSString *doubleconversion = timerSeconds;
    double  timersecondsval = [doubleconversion doubleValue];
    self.cancelVisibility.hidden = NO; 
    self.timerSecondsField.hidden = YES; 
    self.restartTimerVisibility.hidden = YES;
    self.timerStatus.hidden= NO;
    self.timerStatus.text = (@"Timer Running");
       
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timersecondsval target:self selector:@selector(timerStatusUpdater) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
    

}
```

Essentially I want the cancel button to stop the timer and reset the view. I tried using if statements to change the "timersecondsval" to 0 and to make the "timerStatusUpdater" call my view reset function rather than calling the function that plays the alarm sound, but changing the time didn't work so I would have to wait until the timer ended for it to reset the view. (and the view reset crashed my app).

Here is the code for the view reset:

```
-(void) newView{
    self.cancelVisibility.hidden = YES;
    self.timerStatus.hidden = YES;
    self.restartTimerVisibility.hidden = YES;
    self.timerSecondsField.hidden = NO;
    
}
```

I also tried using the cancel function like this to call up a new NSTimer but it didn't cancel out the previous function. Here's the code for that:

```
- (IBAction)cancelPressed:(id)sender {
    
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(newView) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
    
    
}
```

So is there a function I can just add to cancel the previous NSTimer so my cancel button works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timersecondsval ...
```

to start and to cancel you need

```
self.timer.invalidate;
```

**EDIT**

Based on comment - remember you need to declare an `ivar` for this timer in your interface e.g.

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer * timer; // My timer

@end
```

which you can place either in your header or in your class file, depending on wether you like it to be accessible to other classes as well.

Also, note that with ARC you typically declare it as `strong`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got I to work. For other people with the issue, you need to do what they said above plus add a property similar to this, "@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *timer;" to your header file.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Great, I am glad you got it working. Yes, you need an ```ivar``` called ```timer``` together with this which I did not mention explicitly. That ivar really is the timer you were looking for and you should set and cancel it as in the answer and build your logic around that, as I am sure you did based on your comment.

Comment: Thomas, also note the edit with a few refinements based on your comment.